# SQL Many to many query select user friends

Tags: sqlite

I have recently picked up SQL for my web app project for school and I am learning it as I am coding the app, but I have reached a point where I have a many to many relationship between users of the app.

Basically I have an account table with and id a username and a password and another table which stores a user id and the user id of its friend. For my next objective I have to be able to get the username of the friend of the first user with only one query and I don't know how to do that. I've tried a few options with inner join but still haven't been able to select the usernames. Down below you can find attached images of the database, and the two tables.

[Account Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBPtO.png)

[Friends Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdTTH.png)

[Query I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue8di.png)

Comment: Dont post images or links. Post your tables DDL, Sample of data, and SQL instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.

You have `Accounts => Friends => Friends`

It should be `Accounts => Friends => Accounts`

Since you are using the accounts table twice, you need to set an alias each time. In this query, I use acc1 and acc2.

```
SELECT acc1.username, acc2.username FROM
accounts acc1 
INNER JOIN friends ON acc1.id = friends.idUser
INNER JOIN accounts acc2 ON friends.idUserFriend = acc2.id
WHERE acc1.username = 'paRa'
```

Comment: thank you sou much i have seen the answer only now i ve took a break. A bit tired =)) Thank you so much for your help !!!!